# new Date converting invalid date, can't validate dates properly

Tags: javascript

Here's my problem:

```
new Date('02/30/2000')
```

Javascript converts to:

```
Wed Mar 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)
```

I can't validate dates that way, if javascript keeps 'correcting' dates automatically.
I was using `isNaN` to check if date is valid, but I guess it will never work as I want.
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is exactly how the JavaScript `Date` object works. [The MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) describes it quite well as follows:

> ***Note:*** Where *Date* is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. *new Date(2013, 13, 1)* is equivalent to *new Date(2014, 1, 1)*, both create a date for *2014-02-01* (note that the month is 0-based). Similarly for other values: *new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70)* is equivalent to *new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10)* which both create a date for *2013-03-01T01:10:00*.

There is no built-in way to work around this behavior.  However, there are libraries that have been written to solve this and other issues with the Date object.  Specifically, consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
moment('02/30/2000','MM/DD/YYYY').isValid()  // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateString = '01/03/2012';
var checkDate;
var flag = true;

try {
   checkDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateString);
} catch (e) {
     flag = false;
}
if(flag)
    alert('Valid Date');
else
    alert('Invalid Date');
```

Comment: Whoa there - Who said anything about JQuery or a date picker?

Comment: I think it is better to use jquery than using a whole new asset for just validating date

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
var ValidDate = function (string) {
    var dateParts = string.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/),
        year = dateParts[3],
        month = dateParts[1],
        day = dateParts[2];

    var jsDate = new Date(string);

    if (year != jsDate.getFullYear() || month != jsDate.getMonth() + 1 || day != jsDate.getDate()) {
        return NaN;
    }
    return jsDate;
}


console.log(ValidDate("01/05/1989"));   // => Thu Jan 05 1989  ...
console.log(ValidDate("40/05/2010"));   // => NaN
console.log(ValidDate("05/40/2000"));   // => NaN
```